# as3 listening to volume (db) at specific hz

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

I have looked everywhere, but I can't figure out how to do this.

I want to use a simple drum track, and everytime the kick drum goes off, something in my game should rotate.
Figured I could use the volume of that track at around 50hz or so to drive the angle of my object.
And thats where I got stuck, how do I read the volume at 50hz??
I really hope someone could help me with this!

Thanks!

Dennis

Answer (score 0):

If this is still a relevant question, I would advise looking at Bit101's blog, where he posted a [series of tutorials about producing sound](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?s=sound%20synthesis).  The second one is where he talks about producing specific sounds.  (There is a "magic" formula that he uses at one point, described on [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_key_frequencies).)  You can probably use this to backward compile the frequency from a given sound.